# No Opens received with Android Push Notifications

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, push-notification

It appears  that something within our App SDK Configuration within Salesforce Marketing cloud is not functioning where no opens are being received for any Android Pushes. There was a third party company who enabled the Push in the App before my time at the company. And our team just configured the notifications. we understand that in order to track opens, Analytics will need to be set to True in the SDK.
How do we go about fixing this issue..and how can we access the app dev environment??

Comment: You are using the Android MobilePush SDK?

Comment: Yes - from what I understand Android MobilePush SDK was used..

Comment: Do you have an open support case?  If not, start there.  Alternatively, you could post a lot of code you probably don't want public :)

Comment: yes that is the feedback i got form the support case - i just want to know  if there is a way to take over the SDK without knowing who configured it..

Comment: What is the feedback you got from the support case?  If you have not adequately answered your question via the support case then ask for the case to be escalated.  They should have asked you for the output from the SDK's "get state" method and they should have asked you for any code related to the customization of notifications.  This is a solvable problem regardless of who configured your application originally.

NOTE: `do not post` those items here as they will contain "secrets" that you should not share publicly.

Comment: thanks Bill Mote